# How to clear an invalid date field on blur? (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, date

Say I have an `<input>` field with the `type='date'` attribute. When it is untouched, it displays date as mm/dd/yyyy. Is there any way, using AngularJS ng-blur directive to clear the field back to this state when a user enters input, say 03/21/2016, deletes one of the fields (ie 03/dd/2016), and then clicks outside of ('blurs') the field?

Comment: Set  the scope variable `ng-model` binds to to a new `Date()`?

Comment: A new date object has the value of the current date

Comment: Strangely enough, you seem to have to reset it via native JS or jQuery: `$("input").val(null);` - see here: https://jsbin.com/bivuqitefi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Cool, thanks so much! Anyone stumbling upon this question, Johannes' solution works!

Answer (score 0):

ng-blur,

In your html

```
<input type="date" ng-model="date" ng-blur="blured()" />
```

In your controller

```
$scope.blured = function()
{
    // check the date
    // if invalid
    $scope.date = null;
}
```

see also:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur

Comment: This does not have the desired effect because although the model is set to null, the input field view still has the invalid date displayed (ie 02/mm/2017). I need a way to clear the view as well as the model. And in case you are going to ask, the value of $viewValue on invalid input is already set to the empty string so manipulating that does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

> In your HTML

```
<input type="date" ng-model="date" ng-blur="blured(date,$event)" />
```

In your JS

```
$scope.blured= function (inputdate, e) {
          if (!e.ctrlKey && !e.metaKey && (e.keyCode == 32 || e.keyCode > 46))
              doFormat(e.target);
          if (e.target.value.length == 10) {
              $scope.IsValidDate(1, e.target.value);
          }
      }

      //id is used to check which date control
      //method is used to validate entered date in MM/dd/yyyy format
      $scope.IsValidDate = function (id, dateValue) {
          var formats = ['MM/DD/YYYY']
          if (!moment(dateValue, formats).isValid()) {
              if (id == 1) {
                  $scope.date = null;
              }
          }
      }
```

> Hope this work for you, it worked for me.